# How do I write an error to a WebSocket channel in Netty?

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I have a Netty 4.0.19 app where I'm using a TextWebSocketFrames to send and receive messages.

These messages, when they are received, all fire through the "onmessage" event handler.

What would I do to make error messages instead on the onerror handler?

For example, how would the following's error condition be sent back to the web socket client as an error and not a message?

```
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final TextWebSocketFrame msg) throws Exception
{
    final String message = msg.retain().text();

    Envelope envelope = null;
    boolean errorFree = true;

    try
    {
        envelope = EnvelopeJsonEncoder.decode(MessageType.PUBLISH, message).build();
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        errorFree = false;
        final WebSocketFrame outFrame = new CloseWebSocketFrame(1002, "Closing due to error");
        ctx.writeAndFlush(outFrame);
    }

    if (errorFree)
    {
        ctx.fireChannelRead(envelope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would write a CloseWebSocketFrame and specify the right close code and reason.

Comment: I edited the code to use the CloseWebSocketFrame and it closes the socket but does not deliver the "Closing" statement. Neither onerror or onmessage fire now in the client... ?